# Android server crashes

Tags: android, client-server, forceclose, java-client

I have written a small client server application for android. The client is a Java program running on my PC while my Android phone is a server. I'm facing force close issues in my server program. The server starts pretty good, but when I send a string from my PC client, the android application (server) force closes. It has become really annoying. Please help!

Here is my client program running on my PC:

```
package javaNetPackage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class javaClient {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String serverIpAddress = "10.81.242.220";

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            echoSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                               + "the connection to server");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please give number");
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream())),true);
        out.println(str);

    out.close();
    in.close();
    echoSocket.close();
    }

}
```

And here is my server code running on Android:

```
package com.vinit.androidserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ServerSocket ss = null;
       String mClientMsg = "";
       Thread myCommsThread = null;
       protected static final int MSG_ID = 0x1337;
       public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText("Nothing from client yet");
        this.myCommsThread = new Thread(new CommsThread());
        this.myCommsThread.start();     
    }
    @Override
       protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            ss.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Handler myUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_ID:
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv.setText(mClientMsg);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
       };

     class CommsThread implements Runnable {
            public void run() {
                Socket s = null;
                try {
                    ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    Message m = new Message();
                    m.what = MSG_ID;
                    try {
                        if (s == null)
                            s = ss.accept();
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                        String st = null;
                        st = input.readLine();
                        mClientMsg = st;
                        myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            }
     }
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Update:: Okay, I solved the issue of force close. I deleted the permission tags in manifest.xml and re-typed them. But now, I'm facing a different problem here. The sent string from PC client is not getting displayed in my server TextView (textView1 in layout xml, referred to as tv in server code). Default message in tv is "Nothing from client yet". When I send a string from PC client, default message disappears but sent string is not updated in server TextView (tv).

Comment: What does the Android process log tell you about your process? It will give you the name and location of any exception that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the received string to your `Message` object sent in `myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);` instead of your `mClientMsg` field.

You can create and send the `Message` object as below:

```
String st = null;
st = input.readLine();
Message msg = Message.obtain(myUpdateHandler, MSG_ID, st);
msg.sendToTarget();
```

To get the value in your handler,

```
case MSG_ID:
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText((String) msg.obj);
    break;
```

I would suggest you use a `Bundle` object instead of the raw object though. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#setData(android.os.Bundle)

The reason you ends up with an empty string is because your handler and `CommsThread` run in different threads and thus not using the same instance of `mClientMsg`.

i.e. changes in `CommsThread` to `mClientMsg` is not visible in your handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for this silly question though! Why can't we simply write input.readLine() in textView (same thread)?

Comment: @VinitShandilya You can put the reference of TextView as member field like `myCommsThread` and use that in your thread to set the content of TextView.